# term for "location where transaction occurred"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

from an accounting standpoint is there a single word or two word phrase to describe a transaction location or context?

Example:
a transaction occurred in the amount (a) in the main office (o) for a service (s)

a is the amount

s is the item

o is the ?????

Comment: Point of Sale maybe?

Comment: origination point?

Comment: I think the word "location" works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're probably looking for is "Point of Sale."  This is a pretty good definition:  http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/point-of-sale.asp

Answer (score 1):

I would call it the **[locale](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/locale)**

> noun
>  : the place where something happens

(merriam webster)

But I have no reason to think that's the accountancy term for it. If it is clear in the context that it refers to a transaction then I think its meaning will be unambiguous.